# The django grappelli admin panel menu

Tags: django, django-admin, django-grappelli

I have integrated the "django-grappelli" [from here](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli/). This plugin changed my dashboard and all admin designs but is it any ways to add admin panel menu on top. I have checked the django admin-tools but grappelli is work with admin-tools but don't have any good documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a menu on top, this is not supported by django-grappelli at this time. From the [grappelli documentation](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dashboard_setup.html#dashboard-setup):

> **Note**
>
> grappelli.dashboard is a simplified version of Django Admin Tools:
> Bookmarks, Menus and the custom App-Index are not available with
> Grappelli.

Comment: Can admin-tools support multiple admins?

Comment: Yes, http://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/multiple_admin_sites.html

Comment: np i try to add admin-tools menu in grappelli